# i want to make a query to fetch a data between two dates

Tags: oracle

I want to make a query to fetch a data between two dates.  The first date is always the start of the year (like 1 jan 2018) and second date will be the system date. The problem is first date will be dynamically changed when year changed like 1 jan 2018 will dynamically change to 1 jan 2019.

I made a query but I don't know how to make first date dynamic.

```
SELECT * 
FROM id_certs 
where PERIOD BETWEEN to_date('01-Jan-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy') and TO_DATE(SYSDATE);
```

Comment: You need to tag this with the database you are using (mysql, sql-server, db2, etc.), because date functions vary greatly between database products.

Comment: i am using oracle sql developer please help

Comment: You need to add an oracle tag, then, so that Oracle people spot this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
year_end_date DATE;
year_start_date DATE;
new_start_date DATE;
text_field DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY')-1,12) into year_end_date FROM dual;
SELECT TRUNC(SysDate,'YEAR') into year_start_date  FROM Dual;
SELECT add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY')-1,12) + 1 into new_start_date FROM dual;
IF year_end_date = SYSDATE THEN
  text_field := new_start_date;
ELSE
  text_field := year_start_date;
END IF;
  select * from table_name where column_name between text_field and sysdate;
END;


I made this somebody help me to correct this i am not able to fetch data, i am new in pl sql please help.
```